# Regular Expression select up to line break

Tags: regex

I am trying to select everything after `CORP ACT OPTION NO` up until 2 new lines and carriage returns (up to safekeeping account in example)

My reg expression atm to extract the info (all of it after CORP ACT OPTION) is

```
CORP ACT OPTION NO\.([\s\S]*)
```

Sample dara:

```
CORP ACT REFERENCE                  : 007XS0212069115
SENDER'S REFERENCE                  : 1212070800330001
FUNCTION OF MESSAGE                 : NEW MESSAGE
CORP ACT EVENT                      : INTEREST PAYMENT
PLACE OF SAFEKEEPING                : US
ISIN                                : XS0212069115
ISIN/DESCRIPTION                    : KFW 4.750 071212 GBP
METHOD OF INTEREST COMPUTATION      : A006
EX-DATE                             : 20121207
RECORD DATE                         : 20121206
CORP ACT OPTION NO.                 : 001
CORPORATE ACTION OPTION CODE        : CASH
CURRENCY OPTION                     : GBP
RESULTING AMT                       : GBP617,5
PAYMENT DATE                        : 20121207
EXCHANGE RATE                       : GBP/GBP/1,
INTEREST RATE                       : 4,75

SAFEKEEPING ACCOUNT                 : 000000000000
CONFIRMED BALANCE                   : FAMT/13000,
CREDIT/DEBIT IND                    : CREDIT
```

How can I select up until the line break above `SAFEKEEPING ACCOUNT?` Many thanks.

Answer (score 8):

`/.*\s*:\s*.*/g` should work fine. Without `m` the match isn't going to match more than one line.

Explanation of regex:

- `.*` *match as much as possible until followed by:*
- `\s*:` *any amount of spaces (0 or more) followed by a litteral `:` character
- `\s*` *any amount of spaces (0 or more)*
- `.*` *match as much as possible until the linebreak*

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dA0cL1)

You can also use capture groups and check every key with every value:

`/(.*)\s*:\s*(.*)/g`

[**Regex 101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/hA8vO6)

Comment: That has selected everything

Comment: @steven This will match all lines and create capture groups (check the second example).

Comment: I'm not sure why the capture groups would be important to me? The fields will differ in each file

Answer (score 1):

The new line based on your file format, encoding, OS,... could be '\r','\r\n' or '\n'. So you need to match two of any of those, i.e `[\n|\r\n|\r]{2}`

```
'CORP ACT OPTION NO.([\s\S]*)[\n|\r\n|\r]{2}'
```

Comment: SAFEKEEPING ACCOUNT will not appear in every file. It needs to be matched on a new line.

Comment: Ok so replace SAFEKEEPING with two new lines.

Comment: The new line based on your file format, encoding, OS,... could be '\r','\r\n' or '\n'. Plz check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess `(CORP ACT OPTION NO.*?)(?:\r|\n|\r\n){2}` is what you're looking for. Check this [demo](http://regexr.com?33vdl) to see it working. Don't forget the `DOTALL` flag.

Comment: When I use this reg expression without the DOTALL flag, it just does it for one line. I don't have a DOTALL flag to use in my program where I'm inserting the reg expression..